# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' -- BUT IT'S THERE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting the error: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, System.String, Int32, System.String)' all over my elmah logs.

It also logs the URL and the parameter id is present: https://removed.site/removedController/Edit/2973962?eid=000003879145&orgUnitId=26189&page=index&PageSize=100&PageNumber=1&Filter=Active

The parameter id = 2973962 in the above URL.  I have seen many posts that state to use int? instead of int in the action parameters, if I was passing null, I would agree that this is the solution.  But I'm not sure what to do in this instance.

Also, it may be noteworthy to say, I have not seen (or had any users complain about) this error, except for seeing them in the error logs.

EDIT*

I now think this is happening after the 20min IIS session timeout.  The user goes to a page, leaves the computer for 20+ minutes, tries to submit the form, and the server sends them to the GET instead of the POST action.  I was able to reproduce the error with this method.

Is this correct, the server will redirect to the GET after session state is lost? and Does anyone recommend raising the 20min IIS session timeout, and if so, to what?

Comment: What is the signature (parameter types and names) of your Edit method?

Comment: _Also, it may be noteworthy to say, I have not seen (or had any users complain about) this error, except for seeing them in the error logs._ But can you reproduce it?

Comment: @CodeCaster here is the sig public ActionResult Edit(int id, string eid, int orgUnitId, string page).

Comment: @bump I cannot not reproduce it. It's happening with not only this action, but many other actions in my controllers, and happening with a frequency that is concerning